# chrome extensions : How do I navigate to a page on the active tab, and call a function onLoad

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I need a very simple task, and it seems so hard to achieve.

I need to load a url in the active tab, and once loaded I need to call a function in content.js

I'm new to chrome extensions, so there are chances I'm drowning in a cup. What I did is that onClick on a button in my popup, I send a message to content.js to css query the page for the link, and if found click on it and wait until it's done.

My problem is that I cannot find a reliable way to react **after** the page ended loading.
Here's my code:

**popup.js**

```
function goToProfileDetailsPage(generateBtn) {
    generateBtn.addEventListener('click', async () => {
        try {
            const [tab] = await chrome.tabs.query({active: true, currentWindow: true});
            let [{result}] = await chrome.scripting.executeScript({
                target: {tabId: tab.id},
                func: () => {
                    const PROFILE_LINK_SELECTOR = '.feed-identity-module__actor-meta a'

                    const el = document.querySelector(PROFILE_LINK_SELECTOR);
                    if (el) el.click();
                    return !!el;
                },
            });
            if (!result) {
                alert('Please go to your linkedIn profile page before pressing the generate button')
                return
            }
            await new Promise(resolve => {
                chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener(async function listener(tabId, info) {
                    if (tabId === tab.id && info.status === 'complete') {
                        chrome.tabs.onUpdated.removeListener(listener);
                        console.log("Finished loading profile page")
                        await generateCvAndOpenTab(tab)
                        // [{result}] = await chrome.scripting.executeScript({
                        //     target: {tabId: tab.id},
                        //     func: generateCvAndOpenTab,
                        //     arguments:{tab}
                        // });

                        resolve();
                    }
                });
            });

        console.log( "after the onUpdated event" )

        } catch (e) {
            document.body.append(e.message);
        }
    });
}
```

The lines

```
console.log("Finished loading profile page")
```

and

```
console.log( "after the onUpdated event" )
```

are never executed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use executeScript directly in the popup.
For this task there's even no need for messages.

The action popup is an extension page, which has a chrome-extension:// URL and hence is capable of using all granted `chrome` API. The popup is a separate window so it has its own separate devtools: right-click inside the popup and select "inspect" in the menu.

Note that executeScript runs the function/file as a content script in the web page, so this code can access DOM of the web page directly, but it can't access DOM of the popup or any variables or functions in the outer scope. The returned value must be JSON-compatible (string, number, boolean, null, Array/Object of these types), any other types will transfer as undefined or `{}`.

```js
generateBtn.addEventListener('click', async () => {
  try {
    const [tab] = await chrome.tabs.query({active: true, currentWindow: true});
    let [{result}] = await chrome.scripting.executeScript({
      target: {tabId: tab.id},
      func: () => {
        const el = document.querySelector('.feed-identity-module__actor-meta a');
        if (el) el.click();
        return !!el;
      },
    });
    if (!result) return;
    await new Promise(resolve => {
      chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener(function listener(tabId, info) {
        if (tabId === tab.id && info.status === 'complete') {
          chrome.tabs.onUpdated.removeListener(listener);
          resolve();
        }
      });
    });
    [{result}] = await chrome.scripting.executeScript({
      target: {tabId: tab.id},
      func: () => {
        // do something on the new page
      },
    });
  } catch (e) {
    document.body.append(e.message);
  }
});
```

Comment: Hello wOxxOm, thanks for the great answer, I tried to do what you proposed, navigation happens correctly, but no code is executed after it.

I changed my question to show what didn't work for me

Comment: It probably means you have no permissions for the new URL e.g. you've used `activeTab` instead of adding the URL to `host_permissions`. Debug the code in devtools.

Comment: You were right, actually, in your code the onUpdated listener was not triggered because it was too late (the el.click() script has already finished executing at the moment we register that listener (somehow the script waits until the page loads to resolve).

So I had to use a Promise.then syntax to subscribe the onUpdated listener before calling the script.

Now if I call fetch directly without script, it seems to fail generating a CORS violation (althoug the server endpoint is CORS enabled), But when I call it through executeScript it seems to work